# Flatten a Dictionary in Julia

Tags: dictionary, julia, flatten

I have a Dict in Julia

```
In[27]:  CollectedOutputCount
Out[27]: Dict{Any,Any} with 3 entries:
  2 => Any[278963,1,1]
  3 => Any[283339,1,1]
  1 => Any[272878,0,0,0]
```

I want to create an Array from the contents of the Dict consisting of the sum of each Dict entries 2:end. The first value in each Dict entry is a label. The output needs to be something like

```
Output = [ label sum;label sum;...]
```

in this case it would be

```
Output = [278963 2;283339 2;272878 0]
```

Is there any way of doing this apart from iterating in loops ? Is there some function to flatten a Dict into an Array (probably with padding where there are uneven dimensions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about functions that can flatten dictionaries in such custom way, but you can avoid the loops by using `map`:

Given your dictionary:

```
CollectedOutputCount = Dict(2 => [278963,1,1], 3 => [283339,1,1], 1 => [272878,0,0,0], 4 => [1234])
```

You can flatten it into [label sum; label sum...] in one line:

```
vcat(map(a -> [a[1] sum(a[2:end])], values(CollectedOutputCount))...)
```

Which gives you:

```
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
1234  0
278963  2
283339  2
272878  0
```

`map` applies a function to all elements of an array, in this case the values iterator for your dictionary. Then you can append these using `vcat`. Notice how `sum` gave you 0 when there were no values in the dictionary, just the 1 element as a label `(1234 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative equivalent option to the one of @niczky12 but using list comprehension;

```
>>> mydict =  Dict(2 => [278963,1,1], 3 => [283339,1,1], 
                   1 => [272878,0,0,0], 4 => [1234]);
>>> comp = [[a[1] sum(a[2:end])] for a in values(mydict)];
```

The main difference is the use of list comprehensions instead of `map` function. They are equivalent (in this case).

Here `comp` is, however, an array with 4 entries, where each entry is a 1x2 array. To translate it to a `4x2 array`:

```
>>> vcat(comp...)
4x2 Array{Int64,2}:
   1234  0
 278963  2
 283339  2
 272878  0
```

---

If all the arrays of the dictionary have the same length, however, you could concatenate them, and replace the last column:

```
>>> mydict = Dict(2 => [278963,1,0], 3 => [283339,1,1], 1 => [272878,0,0])
>>> vals = hcat(values(mydict)...)';
>>> hcat(vals[:, 1], sum(vals[:, 2:end], 2))
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 278963  1
 283339  2
 272878  0
```

Although, the iterative version is probably more efficient.

---

Last, a completely iterative version, which doesn't create unnecessary temporary storage:

```
r = zeros(Int64, length(mydict), 2)
for (n, b) in enumerate(values(mydict))
    r[n, 1] = b[1]
    r[n, 2] = sum(b[2:end])
end
```